# Mutual Authentication

Tags: authentication, mutual

What are the different types of mutual authentication with some included examples, please? What is the risk of not having it?

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: The reason I asked questions because I believe mutual authentication can happen through digital certificates and also using shared secret keys but I want to know how this really happens in practice. Sorry if my question was poor but I don't have much knowledge on security so found this site so I can ask questions and learn more and more. One of my mentors always says "There is no stupid question in the world". Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. What are the different types of mutual authentication that can happen between infrastructure components? (Eg: between Server and DB, just between servers).**

Authentication is about *proving who you are* (i.e. your identity). In a company's infrastructure, any resources may need to authenticate themselves. These resources could be applications, employees, etc. and the authentication method could be certificates, passwords, etc.

Mutual authentication just means that the two resources need/want to verify the identity of the other one before taking any further step.

**2. What is the risk of not having any kind of mutual authentication?**

The risk is the same as not having any kind of (one-way) authentication: one side will not be sure who it's dealing with. The impact depends on the resources concerned.

Let's take two examples:

- Most of the time, when browsing HTTPS, only the webserver will authenticate itself during the TLS handshake. E.g., Google doesn't need you to prove your identity before letting you look at [what a Tarsius is (Wikipedia).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarsius) Yet, the client (you) wants to be sure that they're browsing Google and not some shady website.
- When business applications communicate with each other, each one may need to verify the identity of the other one. (Imagine two applications handling bank transfers.) In that case, assuming they use TLS, they'll both check the other one certificate. Otherwise, an attacker may impersonate one of the application and cause some trouble to the company.

There's no rule of thumb to decide whether a mutual authentication is needed. You have to assess the risk for each resource and decide whether it needs to authenticate.

Comment: don't answer bad questions.

Comment: @Joe: *Bad* is relative. One may qualify this question as such on the basis that it is too broad, probably because the author doesn't have the knowledge other Security Professionals may have. (But isn't this why people come?)
We always say that security is context-dependent. It depends on the threat model, the business requirement, the environment, etc. This one may be a bad question, but it doesn't mean we cannot provide a good answer, explaining *why* it depends, and on *which* criteria.

Comment: Then make the author ask a better question.  Answering bad questions prevents the site from cleaning them up automatically as well as rewarding the author for asking a poor question,.

Comment: @Yuriko: Thanks for the wonderful explanation about the mutual authentication. Would appreciate your perspective about sharing the knowledge. Could you provide some example or any reference which speaks the practical implementation of it.

Comment: @Joe: I believe I already answered your first point in my comment and through my answer. I agree with your 2nd point, but *bad* is a spectrum and some good can still come out of this question. Anyway, perhaps we could agree to disagree for this case. :-)

Comment: @VinayThivari: Unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge to provide a useful answer for that part.

Comment: @Yuriko: Thanks and your answer makes lot of sense.